# Инверсия зависимости в Unity3D С#

Tags: c#, unity3d, solid, inversion-of-control, di

Ребята, хочу внедрить инверсию зависимости и вот не как голова не поймет как это сделать, туторы смотрю, а результат получается NullReference  в строке:
float x = _controllerService.GetAxisRowX();

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour{
[SerializeField] Character _character;

private int speedForce = 10;

public IPlayerControllerService _controllerService;
public void Inject(IPlayerControllerService controllerService)
{_controllerService = controllerService;}
private void Update()
{
    Move();
}
public void Move()
{
    float x = _controllerService.GetAxisRowX();
    float y = _controllerService.GetAxisRowY();
    Debug.Log($"input keyboard {x}:{y}");
    Vector3 newDirection = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
    _character.transform.position = newDirection.normalized * speedForce * Time.deltaTime;
    
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-моему, вы нигде не инициализируете поле `_inputKeyboard` класса `Injector`, которое потом передается в `PlayerControllerService` и требуется для метода `GetAxisRow()`

Comment: не вставляйте код фотографиями, пожалуйста 

Comment: Принял больше не буду..... я первый раз

Comment: Привет, всем снова решил проблему, спасибо первому комментарию . что подтолкнул меня разобраться получше, инжектор не был инициализирован и был null , поэтому и не работал так же инициализация в _inputKeboard и _character были обвялены но не созданы, не знаю как тут решение добавить, и как вопрос закрыть простите (